Nextjs returning 500 Internal Server error before getting the POST data
I am working on a project lately which had about 100 users and everything is working fine until 1 - 2 users reported that the app is not working for them. When I checked my vercel logs, I noticed a weird issue happening :-
// test.com/api/users/recording/options

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {

  const data = await request.json();
  console.log('Hey we received a new data')
  console.log(data)
  console.log('Succesfully received the data')

In the above api route, when the user makes a post request, it should load the json object and log the values, but before it logs the first demo log, it throws a 500 Internal server error :-
The internal server error
The error doesn't make any sense because either it should have break the app if received the wrong data or throws a new error and explain it, however, the app executes fine and the logged data value is also true
